# VMWare Fusion 7 Pro Networking Issue

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware

My problem is very simple: IF USING WIFI, only the my mac can ping the VM running locally... other machines on the network can't. Suggestion? Ideas? tests to run?

Details:

- Bridged Connection is being used
- VM can ping other machines
- VM can access internet
- VM has IP of 10.10.10.55, my mac IP is 10.10.10.12.
- Same Router (10.10.11.254) and DNS servers (10.10.11.15) for all machines
- VM is not using DHCP.
- There is no IP conflict
- A machine can ping the VM if, and only if, the VM ping that host first
- Pinging based on IPV4, not hostname!

**EDIT 1**

I've managed to narrow it down to the WIFI... If I use the thunderbolt port i can get it working nicely!!! Now I need ideas to figure out if it's OSX Wifi or my corporate Wifi

Comment: Have you added routes for 10.10.10.x <-> 10.10.11.x to your router's routing table?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes! other physical machines (and corporate VMs) communicate fine...

Comment: If you do a traceroute (aka `tracert`) to the machine from one that can't reach it, how far does it make it? What internal subnet mask are you using on the VM, networked machines, and router?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 tracert goes no-where... subnet mask is 255.255.254.0 for everyone...